# Add data to paginator (KnpPaginatorBundle, Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination, knppaginator

I'm using KnpPaginatorBundle.

Let say I've got something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('p.id, p.name, p.description)
   ->from('My\Bundle\Entity\Post', 'p')
   ->where('p.unread is NULL')                
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$posts = $query->getResult();
```

And my paginator:

```
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$posts = $paginator->paginate(
   $posts,
   $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
   3 
);
```

Everythink works very well, but **I would like to add my own data to $posts** by foreach.

My example don't work:

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
   $posts [$key]['filterPath'] = 'example';
}
```

I get error `Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination has no effect`

How can I solve it?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something  like that

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
$tab=$posts[$key];
$tab=['filterPath'] = 'example';
$posts['key']=$tab;
}
```

As far as i remember $posts  isn't normal array and it  cannot be accessed  directly